# How can I inc/dec diffuse_color or specular intensity values of selected object's materials simultaneously?

Tags: materials, edit-mode

For example an appended object doesn't match current scene lighting or to adjust whole scene including lighting.

I've read ideas of using drivers but I am looking for something simpler and quick to use in any blend without setup.

```
Edit:
```

This is for Internal Render, not Cycles or nodes.

I'm looking to select one or more objects, then adjust in some way the Diffuse_Color_Value and Specular_Intensity for all Materials of selected Object(s) by an input amount. Instead of going through changing each setting by needed amount manually.

Comment: will you edit your question to make it more clear. As it is not I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: Do you mean that you are importing a model, that doesn't match and you want to do color grading? If so you can color grade post process in many ways, but the easiest is to learn how to use the compositor with render layers, as anything beyond this has some serious limitations within blender. However, you could possibly get a reasonable output from the 'Color Management' section of the Scene Tab (though it will require that you would have to change your original result). Primarily because I believe you have to change your render result as a whole (somebody correct me here if I'm wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is what you mean, but you can feed values to multiple nodes using the value node...

https://www.blender.org/manual/composite_nodes/types/input/value.html

... With additional nodes between Value and your output nodes, you could vary the factor between two materials, for example, or jack lighting up/down...  But I am not sure if this is what you mean... but it IS a handy "adjust everything here" tool.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm understanding I'm understanding correctly, you can set your material on one object as you need to and then select the objects that should have the same material and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>*>material*. Then all of then selected objects will share the same material data.[image]